# Basic flask application with after_request returns server error

Tags: python, flask

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')
def hello():    
    return "k?"
@app.after_request
def sendsms():
    pass
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

What am I doing wrong? Or do I understand the after_request wrong if so I'd really appreciate an explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.Flask.after_request) is usually a good place to find answers to things like this.

> Your function must take one parameter, a `response_class` object and return a new response object or the same (see `process_response()`).

Your function does neither of those things.

```
@app.after_request
def sendsms(response):
    return response
```